# Google maps marker Z-index above opacity-layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to add a opacity layer between the map and marker icon that that should cover the map but the marker should be above it (higher Z-index).

So far I've tried the :after element for the #map container but this does not work as expected, marker can't be lifted above it.

```
#map:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.2;
    background-color: #3388ff;
}
```

I've also tried adding a div to the controls layer like this

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(document.getElementById('overlay_map'));
```

But I'm still unable to achieve higher z-index for the marker since the #overlay_map is added as the same level div than the iframe for the map not inside the iframe. Here's the full code:

```
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {lat: 59.438936, lng: 24.761484};

                var mapOptions = {
                          zoom: 16,
                    center: myLatLng,
            disableDefaultUI: true,

                    styles: [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#111419"},{"lightness":40}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#f9fbff"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#f9fbff"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ecf0f4"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"lightness":"-4"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f9fbff"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#d9dfe8"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f9fbff"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#e5eaf0"},{"lightness":17}]}]
                };

                var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    optimized: false,
                    zIndex:99999999,
                    map: map,
                      icon:'<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/map_pin.svg'
                });
                map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(document.getElementById('overlay_map'));

}
  window.initMap = initMap;
```

I've attached two images: current result / what I'm trying to achieve. 
Any advice on how to achieve this? Can this be achieved via styling of the map?

Current result (marker below opacity layer):
[image]

Result looking for (marker above opacity layer):
[image]

Comment: Use a Google Maps Polygon / Rectangle.

Comment: Would that work as we zoom out? Wouldn't that leave just a blue box on the map? @MrUpsidown

Comment: If you cover the whole world with the polygon, it would work as you zoom out.  Your other option is to attach you opacity layer to the map under the pane that has the markers on it. ([doc on map panes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view#MapPanes))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using Polygin fill for the whole world, as the following code:

```
  var TheWorld = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(0, -90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(0, 90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(90, -90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(90, 90),
  ];

  ThisIsIt = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [TheWorld],
    strokeColor: "#3388ff",
    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#3388ff",
    fillOpacity: 0.5
  });

  ThisIsIt.setMap(map);
```

Thanks for the helpers in the comment.